# Tabview behaviour changes in Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I’ve got an app that uses SwiftUI and has a tab view at the bottom of the app to navigate between the pages. When it was compiled and built in Xcode 13 the tab view goes somewhat transparent with part of the background image showing through. Image 1 is the view from Xcode 13. Image 2 is the view as seen in previous versions of Xcode.

What do I need to change to restore the look from the earlier versions?

Image 1:
[partially transparent tabview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goY6B.jpg)

Image 2:
[original tabview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhFcc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From iOS 15 `TabView` changes its appearance when the content underneath it scrolls.  If the scroll view is near the top then the tab bar's appearance is determined by `standardAppearance`.  If it's near the bottom it uses `scrollEdgeAppearance`.  The default `scrollEdgeAppearance` is transparent, causing the behviour you see.

To make the tab view have a white background in both scenarios you could add something like this to the `TabView`'s `onAppear` block:

```
let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundColor = .white
            
UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```